# laravel 4 centos 7 storage permission

Tags: laravel-4, permissions, storage, centos7

Hi I deploy my laravel4 script form my notebook to production on own VPS server with CentOS7 by git. I have problem with permission to storage folder. I obtain the error

```
 file_put_contents(/var/www/myweb/app/storage/views/0353b2081a97162a6d5fdda4c3a3f918): failed to
```

open stream: Permission denied

i try change permission to storage directory by this by this

```
 cd app/

chown -R apache:apache storage

cd storage/

find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

but the error is still same. How I must set permisiion for solve this problem on CentOS 7 ?

Comment: I was just thinking, have you checked if it has made the folder changes
I normally use this command line to change write permission
chmod –R  775 /var/www/yoursite/app/storage

Comment: the storage directory has owner apache:apache with permisiion 775

Comment: Just to test, can you make it to 777 and test and let me know

Comment: yes with chmod -R 777 is now function. But this isnt safe?

Comment: now when I changed permission back to 775 is still function. The solutions from the link I before i wrote the question. Maybe is problem with deploy form git pull ?

Comment: could be, any way good luck with it

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but still ...

It seem to be a selinux problem.

I installed my Laravel application in /opt/web/myapp and did all the steps mardon did. No luck.

Then I did `sudo setenforce Permissive` and it worked.

I'll be back with the proper selinux labels after a few tests.